# django foreign key relationships

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Hub(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_trainer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    hub = models.ForeignKey(Hub, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    hub_position = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    mentor = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    terms = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'terms']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student:dashboard', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Confused on how to design the models here. Each User can belong to exactly one Hub.A hub has one leader, many excoms and many members ,all of them belongs to User .The hubs are added from the admin side.Leader can accept hub joining requests from excoms and members.

Comment: what's an "excom" ?  What's a "leader" ? What's a "member" ?

Comment: A hub has one user as a leader, many members and many excoms ....leader ,excom and members are Users itself @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Uhu, I guess that's what you meant by "all of them belongs to User" then. Also, what's the difference between an "excom" and a member  ?

Comment: Thats irrelevant .Excoms has certain privilages compred to members @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: When asking for help, you have to let the peoples willing to help you judge what's relevant or not (well, unless they ask for your credit card number of course but that's not the case here).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers       I said that so as not to confuse you . I said thats irrelevant because i know it is .

Comment: If a member is not the same thing as an excom then the difference IS relevant, because it might (or not...) impact the proper modeling. Remember that _we_ don't know anything about your project. Asking for details (that may or not be or seem relevant) when something isn't quite clear is part of our job as developpers, when we fail to do so (or accept answers such as "it's irrelevant") we can be sure the solution will fail to match the customer's needs one way or another, and it might even end up with a complete rewrite. I've seen this quite a few times.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Sorry for my comment. Im learning everyday.Thanks,ill keep that in mind

Comment: No problem, I didn't take it as a personal offfense. I just wanted to make sure that what I could answer would have a chance to be correct.

Comment: You say that "Each User can belong to exactly one Hub". Literally, this means that one given user cannot be at the same time excom or member of one given hub and leader of another one. Do you confirm that it's the correct requirement ?

Comment: That is correct. Leaders for all hubs are decided by the admin. For a user to become member of a hub ,his request should be accepted by an excom.There can be multiple excoms for a hub. Also the leader can promote a member to excom position. Sorry for the delay @brunodesthuilliers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add the user position as a [choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) to the `User`, so you get a nice select box in the Admin.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_POSITIONS = ((0, 'Regular'), (1, 'Leader'), (2, 'Excom'))

    hub = models.ForeignKey(Hub, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    hub_position = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=USER_POSITIONS, ...)
```

Comment: The hub could be a null field ,so how can default be set to 0 .A user cannot be amember if he is not part of any hub

Comment: Im getting this error when i run migrate :s.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Comment: This design allow for more than one leader for a given hub.

Comment: How do i filter all users who are excoms from this?  @brunodesthuilliers